# Circuit composer RX or RY gate disappears

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-inspire

When I specify the RX or RY gate to rotate by say $\pi/4$ in the circuit composer, the gate disappears off the circuit. Is there any reason why if I leave it with $\pi/2$ default then it stays?

**If I edit theta the gate disappears.**

Here's some screenshots to show what happens:

[image: I add the gate RX the default Theta is pi/2]
[image: I double click on the gate and change Theta to pi/4]
[image: ave/implement the change I click on "Your circuit" to go back to the circuit, and the gate is gone]

Ok solution is to erase the whole field $\pi/2$ and reenter $\pi/4$ but leaving $\pi/$ and then denominator $4$ will not work. Also the denominator is bounded between 1 and 9.

[image: Update and disable]

Comment: I am not seeing this with mine... can you attached a picture of what you are seeing?

Comment: That is interesting because I definitely don't see that with mine.

Comment: I think it is a bug within the IBM Quantum Experience Circuit Composer. Because if you change the parameters using the Code Editor then the gates do not disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This is really weird and it is probably a bug within the IBM Quantum Experience Circuit Composer.

So if you change the gate angle like what you did, by clicking on the gate and change the parameter there directly then it **definitely disappeared** from the circuit:

[image]

---

But if you **changed the parameters from the QASM Code Editor** then the gates  **DO NOT disappeared**:

[image]